# Union of two sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let
\begin{align}
X &= \{ (x,y) : 1 < x,y < 3\} \\
Y &= \{ (x,y) : 2 < x,y < 4 \} \\
&\textrm{and} \, , \, \, X \, , \, Y \, \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2
\end{align}
I thought that
$$
X \cup Y =\{ (x,y) : 1 < x,y < 4\}
$$
but when I draw both sets I obtain
[[image: Union of sets <span class=]$X$ and $Y$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYbRb.jpg)

How can I obtain this via rules of set theory and is there a way to represent this new set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drawing is correct. No rules needed, simply think about it logically:

$$
X \cup Y = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon \text{EITHER } (x \text{ AND } y \in (1,3)) \text{ OR } (x \text{ AND } y \in (2,4))\}.
$$